# How to close a particular instance of Exe file using bat file if more than one instances are open from different directories

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting, taskkill, tasklist

Please Help me in this out that I have two instances of the same EXE file running at same time and I want to close only one of them, Both exe are running at the same time and we want to close one using bat file.

If I am using this code.

```
@echo off
cd "D:\demoFolder\" 
taskkill /f demo.exe
pause
```

but it is closing all the instances of Exe it found.
I run this demo.exe from two directories and I want to close the one from a certain directory.

Comment: See, if `wmic process where name="demo.exe" get commandline, executablepath, processid /value` gets you somewhere. Might be helpful. Or not. (depends on your EXE and the way you start them) If you can identify the app you want to close, we can go from there.

Comment: You could try `FOR /F "tokens=2" %%i IN ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq YOUR.EXE" /SVC /NH') DO taskkill /F /PID %%i & EXIT /B` as a batch one-liner... Idk if your windows version support this.

Comment: @7three:  would close the first match, which might not be the right one.

Comment: @Stephan Which one is the right one? ;)

Comment: @7three Several executables with the same name but in different locations (folders). They want to close the one from a specific location (this information is from a "non-answer" to another question). Vipul, you might want to include that important info into your question to avoid too generic answers.

Comment: @Stephan I have run this demo.exe from two directory and I want to close second one but it is closing both of exe(s).

Comment: @VipulGarg, more clarification is needed still. When you say "I have run this demo.exe from two directory", what do you mean? 1. You have two files named `demo.exe` each in different locations; 2. You have only one `demo.exe` and ran it from the command line when your current directories were different when doing so; 3. You have one or more `demo.exe` files, and ran it/them when you were at a remote location, and again when you were located at a different computer.

Comment: @Stephan You are absolutely correct for example you can take example of desktop application, two instance of that application are running from different drives but I want to close specific one using bat file because if I am using taskkill command on its Image name then it is closing both instances.

Comment: @Compo I have a desktop application exe which I have kept in two directories and I am running the running from both directory at the same time. So I want to create a batch script so that I can close specific one instead of closing both of the exe

Comment: You still haven't answered my question (very first comment). I've got an idea, but I need that info to know if it is going to work.

Comment: for example I have exe name "you.exe" and it is running from two directories 1. "C:\Vipul garg1\you.exe" and 2. "C:\Vipul garg2\you.exe" but i want to  close you.exe which is running from "C:\Vipul garg1\you.exe" this directory not the both.

So I am using this script

Comment: for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%b in ('wmic process where "ProcessId=!processId!" get ExecutablePath /value')

Comment: But this script is returning "C:\Vipul". I think it is breaking if it find space in between executable path.

Comment: What's the exact output of **my** command line?

Comment: Returned output is like "C:\Vipul

Comment: There is no way, `wmic process where name="demo.exe" get commandline, executablepath, processid /value` could output `C:\Vipul`.

Comment: @Stephan your command line is closing only one exe but not according to me. It is closing as it find first. But I want to close exe according to header "Image path Name". Image path name contains the Full executable path from where exe is running.

Comment: @Stephan Please try to understand By this way (wmic process where name="demo.exe" get commandline, executablepath, processid /value), I can get full Executable path and then match the executable path and if matches then i can close the exe using its PID.

Comment: Main reason is that you explicitely added `SPACE` to the delimiters. You can force `wmic` to a different output format to avoid the tabular display (see my answer) My question wasn't aimed to be a solution but for clarification, that's why I used `/value` - which makes it easier to read, but more difficult to parse

Answer (score 0):

I made a little batch script. But I only tested it a single path exe. I think it should be ok...

```batch
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM SET "EXE=to the name of your exe"
REM if you don't want an user input
:EXE
SET "EXE="
SET /P EXE=Please enter your file.exe : 
IF "!EXE!" == "" (
   ECHO Empty. Try again.
   GOTO :EXE
)

REM SET "FPATH=to your exe"
REM if you don't want an user input
:PATH
SET "FPATH="
SET /P FPATH=Please enter your path to file.exe : 
IF "!FPATH!" == "" (
   ECHO Empty. Try again.
   GOTO :PATH
)
IF NOT EXIST "!FPATH!" (
   ECHO Path is invalid. Try again.
   GOTO :PATH
)
IF NOT EXIST "!FPATH!\!EXE!" (
   ECHO Path to executable is invalid. Start over again. ;^)
   GOTO :EXE
)

REM Comment from Stephan (the gr8 one-liner)
SET "PID="
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=," %%a IN ('"wmic process where name="!EXE!" get executablepath,processid /format:csv | find "!FPATH!""') DO SET "PID=%%a"

IF DEFINED PID (
   ECHO PID %PID% found. Terminating in T- PING 3000
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 3000 >NUL
   taskkill /F /PID %PID% >NUL
   ECHO Have a nice day.
   EXIT /B
)

ECHO No PID for "!FPATH!\!EXE!" found.
```

Tnx ***again*** to Stephan for the input.

**Update**

✅ I tested it with a random app inside two different folders. It works for me.

❌<s>Btw.: `SET /A "TESTNUM=%%i"` converts input into an number. I don't think there is a ProcessID Cero? It is to handle the output of `tasklist` if no PID is found at all.</s>

Comment: `IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0"` [doesn't work in the `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028). Change to `if not errorlevel 1 set ...`.

Comment: @Stephan You're right, chief. Was looking for a app to test it. I've to do some modifications. Tnx. But I'm close... ;)

Comment: Try this one-liner to get the PID: `for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%a in ('"wmic process where name="%EXE%" get executablepath,processid /format:csv | find "%ExecPath%""') do set "PID=%%a"
`

Comment: @Stephan How mean. I was just at the end. But without a tmp file is of course better ;)

Comment: `set /a` is to  do **a**rithmetic (interpreting strings as INT32). ALL variables in `cmd` are strictly STRING (even the result of a `set /a`; there simply are no other variable types).

Comment: @Stephan `SET /A ADF=0xF` returns decimal 15. But alphabetical chars or random text 0?

Comment: `0xF` is a string, which `set /a` interprets as a hexadecimal number and interprets it as such. `%ADF%` then contains the *string* `15` (may seem a weird concept if you are used to other programming languages)

Comment: @Stephan Yes. So I converted the output of tasklist to an Int Number which is good for a PID. If tasklist returns some other text it's 0. If not we got a number of PID. It's maybe a little hacky but I'm not a genius like you. ;)

Comment: As written, it returns either a PID or nothing (`%PID%` unchanged, why it's good practice to delete the variable ('set "PID="`) before setting it with `for`), which is already covered with `if defined`

Comment: @Stephan Depends on how fast can you spam ctrl c? ;) It's just a "define a var to the initial value" thing. But it don't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have the same executable (or different executables with the same name - doesn't matter) stored in different locations and you run both/all of them at the same time and want to close the one from a certain location only.

`Wmic` is able to get you some details about a process, like PID (which you will need to close a certain process) and the exact location of the executable (which you already know). So list all the processes of your executable and filter for the known location to get the PID.

```batch
    @echo off
    set "execpath=%cd%" & REM or wherever the app you want to close resides
    set "execapp=demo.exe"
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%a in ('"wmic process where name="%execapp%" get executablepath, processid,status /format:csv |find /i "%execpath%\%execapp%""') do taskkill /pid %%a
```

Note: we don't need `status`, it's just to avoid that `wmic` output ends with the needed `PID`, because `wmic` has that ugly line ending of `CRCRLF`. The additional `CR` makes life difficult. (that's only one way to get rid of the `CR` there are others, more generic, but it's good enough here)

Of course you can replace the taskkill command with `set "pid=%%a"` and work from there - it's up to you.

Note: `taskkill` will send a "termination signal" to the application. If your application asks for confirmation/save, there's no clean solution, but you can force the app to close with the `/f` switch (try without first!). Note that this would be a real "kill" - it will not save any progress it made (like "notepad" would just close without saving an altered file)